# how to get a search box using jhipster:import-jdl?

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

Lets say that we have a book and author entities in JDL-Studio like this:

```
entity Book {
    name String required minlength(2)
}

entity Author {
    name String required minlength(2)
}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Book{author(name)} to Author{book}
}
```

When we run the show, we can login and create a new book, but we need to choose between the list of authors in the dropdown list that we have already created in the author entity, right?

How can we do this 2 things using jhipster:import-jdl:

1) tell Jhipster-JDL to create a search box to look in a list of authors (let's say we have a 1000 author entries) and 
2) have a text box where we can add a new text creating a new author entry in the database (or think about a tag for the book: adventures, science-fiction,... but not using the already created from the list).

- Is it posible to do that when creating de JDL-Studio Entities? Is there any place with more advanced use cases besides https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/
- Would it be possible with jhipster-uml? Is UML, more powerful? https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-uml/

Comment: JHipster generates only basic UI. what you want is not covered by JDL.. As UML uses JDL.so it cannot help.There's a pending pull request  that is a bit stale, maybe you could help https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6618

Comment: Thank you very much again, Gaël. If I can help with something that is not programming, please let me know. I am suffering to do the basics here.

Comment: I suggest you train yourself on Angular and uses a UI component library in addition to what JHipster generates. I usually recommend PrimeNG but there are others too like Vmware Clarity or Angular Material.